# Save the same userId in two different column | .NET

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

Have a strange situations after save in DB.

I have entity for update where are two columns `FirstUserId`, `SecondUserId`
In DB they have value
`FirstUserId = 5bbb89ce-ac02-4087-a90f-f267dc1e17b4`
`SecondUserId = 1d4ea841-2dea-4c29-87a1-0b21a5ec61a2`

I set during update

`FirstUserId = 1d4ea841-2dea-4c29-87a1-0b21a5ec61a2`
`SecondUserId = 5bbb89ce-ac02-4087-a90f-f267dc1e17b4`

And In result I have the same Ids in both columns.

My code

```
         await _unitOfWork.Commit();
        if (notifyWaitingAccept.Data != null)
        {
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.FirstUserId = userId;
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.SecondUserId = otherUserId;
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.ModifiedBy = new Guid(userId);
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.IsActive = true;
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.IsRead = false;
            notifyWaitingAccept.Data.IsExecuted = false;

            var resultNotification = _unitOfWork.Notifications.Upsert(notifyWaitingAccept.Data);
            await _unitOfWork.Commit();
            if (!resultNotification.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return OperationResult<UserContactAndNotificationDTO>.Error();
            }
        }
```

As you can see I have the `.Commit()` before set new value.
After first commit my value in DB is normal. Two columns have different values.

After `.Upsert(notifyWaitingAccept.Data)` I have the same value in both columns.

`UserId` and `OtherUserId` always have different values. I really don't know what to do.

Method Upsert

```
public virtual OperationResult<T> Upsert(T entity)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _dbSet.Update(entity);
        return OperationResult<T>.Success(result.Entity);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return OperationResult<T>.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Screen from DB

[image]
During debug I have always differents values

Where do I set the same values?